# Get months name array in different langualge

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In **default language (en)** works fine.

```
moment().format('LL'); \\ 25 December 2014
moment.months(); \\ ["January", "February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
```

Now with different language - **(pt-br)**

```
var pt = moment().locale('pt-br');
pt.format('LL'); \\ 25 de dezembro de 2014
pt.months(); \\ 11
```

`pt.months();` - Why not it returns array of month names ?

Is there different method to get month array ?

Comment: Does your locale define the month names in the first place? (As described in http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/month-names/)

Comment: I have included "moment-with-locales.min.js". So Should I need to define months names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the variable `pt` is an *instance* of a moment object, representing a specific point in time.  The `months` function of a moment object returns the month number of that instance, 0 through 11.

To get the names of the months, you call the `moment.months()` function, from the moment *global*.  Setting the language is an independent operation.

```
moment.locale('pt');
var months = moment.months();

//    ["janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", 
//     "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro"]
```